# How to hover over img and make and change link color?

Tags: css, html

I'm curious as to why this doens't work? My guess is that whatever element your targeting you have to go through its parent. Am I right or is there a trick? (no jquery)

Checkout the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eMw5C/

HTML

## This doesn't work

[image]
            Trigun

```
    <h1>This Works</h1>
    <div class="yes-working">
        <img src="https://i158.photobucket.com/albums/t109/hp_arianepotter/trigun-1.png" />
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Trigun</a>
    </div>

    /* This doesn't work */
    .not-working img { width: 10em; clear: both; }
    .not-working img:hover a { color: red; }
    .not-working a { color: black; }
    .not-working a:hover { color: red; }

    /* This works */
    .yes-working img { width: 10em; clear: both; }
    .yes-working:hover a { color: red; }
    .yes-working a { color: black; }
    .yes-working a:hover { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the non working example, the anchor tag is not child of the img tag.

```
.not-working img:hover a { color: red; }
```

Should be:

```
.not-working img:hover ~ a { color: red; }
```

Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/eMw5C/1/

Comment: Wow dude! I haven't seen that one yet. Very nice... So what does that ~ thing mean? it allows us to pinpoint sister/brother elements, basically? Is this compatible with IE8+ ?

Comment: "General sibling selector" Works in IE 7 and above. http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Answer (score 1):

you have invalid path selector on `.not-working` class.. try this :
`.not-working img:hover ~ a { color: red; }`

syntax (AFAIK) : 
"~" mean select next object
">" mean select children object in one step level bellow

but I don't think you can re-select parent object

CMIIW

Answer (score 0):

Because `.not-working img:hover a` means that your anchor tag `<a>` is inside the `img` tag which is not true. It is true in the second case and that's why it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Its worked :

```
.not-working img { width: 10em; clear: both; }
.not-working:hover a { color: red; }
.not-working a { color: black; }
.not-working a:hover { color: red; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aldiunanto/eMw5C/2/